# Righ way to pass interface address into bind

Tags: c, sockets

Im working od UDP app and I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. I need to get address into `addr.sin_addr.s_addr`. Until now I just used `addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY)` but I will need to set specific address goten from user. Am I doing it right when I use `addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(adresa)`?

Full code:

```
int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
    strcpy(adresa, "someadress");

    int optval;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;//, incoming_addr;

    /* create socket */
    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
        err("socket()");
    }

    /* set reusable flag */
    optval = 1;
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval));

    /* prepare inet address */
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if(strcmp(adresa, "-") == 0)
    {
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* listen on all interfaces */        
    }
    else
    {
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(adresa); /* listen on all interfaces */
    }


    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        err("bind");
    }

    for(;;)
    {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is with the [`inet_addr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_addr) function, which can take an IPv4 address and convert it to an address in network byte order as an `in_addr_t`.   This value can then be stored in `sin_addr.s_addr`:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(adresa);
```